# Digitally signed my macro and it still won't run in excel

Tags: vba, excel, digital-signature

I have made a VBA script in an Excel file. I don't want to allow all scripts to run because of security reasons so I set my Excel to work with `Disable all macros except digitally signed macros` Then I made a signature and signed my script. still when I try to run it, I get the following message:

```
Because of your security settings, macros have been disabled. 
To run macros, you need to re-open this workbook, and then choose to enable macros
```

I would really not like to allow unrestricted use of maros, is there really no other way of using my own macro?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I'm using Microsoft Office Excel 2007 12.06.6771.5000

Comment: Can you confirm that the VBA of the workbook is digitally signed correctly? If you open the VB-Editor and choose from menu `Extras` › `Digital Signature` does it show a certificate name in both positions? And are you sure that you trusted that certificate in Windows (if it is self made certificate)?

Comment: I believe this is a bug with one of the newer Microsoft Office updates. I had a similar problem on Outlook and had to revert back to 15.0.4859.1002 to get it to work. Probably not the answer you're looking for, but if you can get it working after reverting back to this update, you can at least be assured that you're in the same boat, in which case you'll probably need to wait for an MS fix.

Comment: @Peh I made the certificate myself and I made the code myself as well so I personally trust it 100% If I go into the `Tools->Digital Signature` option I can see `The VBA project is currently signed as Certificate name: MyMacros` and under that `Sign as Certificate name: MyMacros` It's entirely possible that I didnT1 do it right, but I did follow a how-to page on the microsoft website.

Comment: @finjo Thank you for the tip, I totally forgot to mention that I'm using an older version of office, I have edited my question to mention it. Sadly I don't think I can revert back any more without my win8 exploding

Comment: @WolfyD when I say you need to trust the certificate I do not mean you personally have to trust it but your computer has to. So it need to be defined as a trusted certificate first. Therefore see in Excel Options › Trust Center › Button "Preferences for Trust Center"  and see if your certificate is within the list of *Trusted Publishers*. If it is not you need Windows to trust this certificate.

Comment: @Peh Whow that was extremely helpful. I checked the trusted publishers and sure enough my certificate is not on that list. I guess that's just something they forgot to mention in the tutorial I was following. Thank you very much

Comment: Made an answer, It think this question might be useful in future for other people too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need to be sure that the VBA of the workbook is digitally signed correctly. If you open the VB-Editor and choose from menu `Extras` › `Digital Signature` it must show a certificate name in both positions.
2. The certificate needs to be trusted. Therefore see in `Excel Options` › `Trust Center` › `Button "Preferences for Trust Center"` and see if your certificate is within the list of `Trusted Publishers`. If it is not you need Windows to trust this certificate.
   See here how to [trust SSL certificate to local system account](https://superuser.com/questions/370217/trust-ssl-certificate-to-local-system-account).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Your answer helped a lot!
As an addition this site was helpful in the process of making my certificate trusted https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sbs/2008/05/08/installing-a-self-signed-certificate-as-a-trusted-root-ca-in-windows-vista/